# makefile in fedora22 syntax error

Tags: makefile, g++, fedora

Im facing a problem that discussed many many many times in whole web, but none of those solutions didnot work with me.
I have a makefile:

```
  1 SHELL:=/bin/bash -O extglob
  2 CC=g++                                                        
  3                                                               
  4 CFLAGS=-c -Wall                                               
  5                                                               
  6 compile:                                                      
  7     $C(CC) $(CFLAGS) mauth.cpp
```

mauth.cpp is just blank int main function, that compiles normally using g++ mauth.cpp.
but when i try doing it using makefile it gives me error:

```
       (CC) -c -Wall mauth.cpp
       /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `-c' 
       /bin/bash: -c: line 0: `(CC) -c -Wall mauth.cpp'
       makefile:7: recipe for target 'compile' failed
       make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

If i remove $(CC) $(CFLAGS) to just g++ -c -Wall mauth.cpp makefile works perfectly. 
i have extglob on:

```
[a@localhost mauth]$ shopt | grep extglob
extglob         on
```

Again none of solutions i found in internet worked for me.
Please help me out.

PS im using fedora22

Problem solved!!!
I changed CC=g++ to C=g++ and it did the job.

Comment: Are you sure you've got `$C(CC)`, and not `$(CC)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your makefile is incorrect and bogus. This:

```
compile:                                                      
        $C(CC) $(CFLAGS) mauth.cpp
```

Should be this instead:

```
compile:                                                      
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mauth.cpp
```

Actually, to make it *really* correct, you need:

```
compile:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) mauth.cpp
```